# Error calling web3.eth.Contract send() function gives error: Method not found

Tags: web3js, send

I just deployed a contract and wants to access it using web3 to read and write data.

I have web3 working, passed the contract Address and ABI and I can access the contract and Read Data using:

contract.methods.getPrice().call()

This returns the correct value from the contract.

However, If i want to write something using send() like:

contract.methods.setTestString("Test").send( {from: account }, function(error, transactionHash){
alert(error);
});

I get the error "Method not found". But the method is there and it is also public available.

Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: we need more information, like web3 version, using ganache , truffle?

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for my sets:

```
        async function setAnString() {
            var varSetAnString = await contract.methods.setAnString( "As you want" ).send()
            .then((result) => {
                    console.log("Success! Got result: " + result);
                    console.log("The value setted: "+varSetAnString);
                    let tmp = JSON.stringify(result,null,1); console.log("result::"+ tmp);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Failed with error: " + err);
                });
        }
        setAnString();
```

Be careful with the ABI. Maybe you need to update.
Hope it helps.

UPDATE:

I previously declare the contract and from address in external options:

```
const contract = new web3js.eth.Contract(abi);

contract.options.from = '0x0.......';
contract.options.address = '0x0.......'; //Contract address
```